# selecting first result from output of a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

i want to select first and last outcome from a subquery in oracle.
i cant use "rownum" since i am using "order by" which completely changes the sequence of "rownum".
pls suggest some solutions.
thanx fr help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use "rownum" because you want both the first and the last values - otherwise you could use rownum by putting your code in a subquery and selecting from it and filtering by rownum in the outer query. As it is, you need to use ROW_NUMBER() analytic function and such (both with order by ... and with order by ... desc, so you can get both the first and the last outcome in one single outer query.

If ties are possible you may prefer DENSE_RANK to get all rows tied for first (or for last); instead, ROW_NUMBER() will return "one of" the rows tied for first (or for last); which one, specifically, is random.

If you want to see an example, provide sample data for your problem.

Comment: yes i used  ROW_NUMBER() with OVER and it worked. thnx

Answer (score 1):

Use `keep` if you have an aggregation query.  That is what it is designed for.  It looks something like this:

```
select x,
       max(outcome) keep (dense_rank first order by datetime asc) as first_outcome,
       max(outcome) keep (dense_rank first order by datetime desc) as last_outcome,
from t
group by x;
```

Use `first_value()` and `last_value()` if there is no aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(outcome) over (partition by x order by datetime) as first_outcome,
       last_value(outcome) over (partition by x order by datetime) as last_outcome
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using ROW_NUMBER() function with OVER(order by..).